# JavaScript - removing previous fieldset once radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to modify this JSFiddle I found because it's almost exactly what I am looking for. Currently all previous decisions are shown, I don't want the previous decisions to show. I just want one answer up at a time. So once you click a radio button I want that question to disappear and to display the next question. I've been playing about with the code for a while and can't figure it out, but I'm not knowledgable enough.

I'm sure it's somewhere in here:

```
$('fieldset.option0').removeClass('hide');
    for (i = 0; i < options.length; i += 1) {
    options_buffer += options[i];
    $('fieldset.option' + options_buffer).removeClass('hide');
  }
```

I've managed to only remove it from the very first click, but after that, all decisions show up.

Here is the JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/danw/h8CFe/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a modified jsFiddle with the desired behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/h8CFe/121/

I modified the last lines of the `update` function to this:

```
    fieldsets.addClass('hide');
    for (i = 0; i < options.length; i += 1) {
        options_buffer += options[i];
    }
    $('fieldset.option' + options_buffer).removeClass('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you can just add hide class to the fieldset you want to hide. For example on clicking first set of radio button you can call $('.step1').addClass('hide') to hide that fieldset.